# A description of the mean of the Geometric Distribution - is it unorthodox or just incorrect?

Tags: probability, distributions, estimation, method-of-moments, geometric-distribution

I have a homework assignment where I'm asked to propose an estimator for the mean of a geometric random variable. This seemed simple enough, given that I've always understood the mean of the geometric distribution to be $1\over{p}$. The directions, however, describe it this way:

Recall that the mean of a geometric random variable $X$ is given by $\theta = \exp(\mathbb E[\log(X)])$

I cannot understand this construal of the mean of a geometric distribution. I've tried manipulation with MGFs and it still doesn't make sense. Is there a typo in the homework directions or is this legitimately a way of describing the mean of X? If it's the latter, how does it work?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

$\exp(\mathbb E[\log(X)])$

is the *[geometric mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_mean)* of a positive random variable $X$

not the mean of a *[geometric random variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution)*.

So either the homework directions put the words in the wrong order, or you transcribed them incorrectly

Comment: Seems like the directions put the words in the wrong order. Thank you!